# Python print statement returns syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

I have no idea why, but every time I attempt to compile the following python code, it highlights my print statements and states that there is a syntax error. I am at a loss for what said error is and I can't locate anyone else with the exact same problem.

```
>mode = input("Is you text in morse code? y/n")
if(mode == y):
    print(" ")
else:
    list = list(input("Enter English text:")
    for i in list
        if (i == "a")
            print("ewfew" if i == a")
            //print(".-", end=" ")
        if (i == "b")
            print("-...", end=" ")
         if (i == "c")
            print("-.-.", end=" ")
         if (i == "d")
            print("-..", end=" ")
         if (i == "e")
            print(".", end=" ")
         if (i == "f")
            print("..-.", end=" ")
         if (i == "g")
            print("--.", end=" ")
         if (i == "h")
            print("....", end=" ")
         if (i == "i")
            print("..", end=" ")
         if (i == "j")
            print(".---", end=" ")
         if (i == "k")
            print("-.-", end=" ")
         if (i == "l")
            print(".-..", end=" ")
         if (i == "m")
            print("--", end=" ")
         if (i == "n")
            print("-.", end=" ")
         if (i == "o")
            print("---", end=" ")
         if (i == "p")
            print(".--.", end=" ")
         if (i == "q")
            print("--.-", end=" ")
         if (i == "r")
            print(".-.", end=" ")
         if (i == "s")
            print("...", end=" ")
         if (i == "t")
            print("-", end=" ")
         if (i == "u")
            print("..-", end=" ")
         if (i == "v")
            print("...-", end=" ")
         if (i == "w")
            print(".--", end=" ")
         if (i == "x")
            print("-..-", end=" ")
         if (i == "y")
            print("-.--", end=" ")
         if (i == "z")
            print("--..", end=" ")
         if (i == "1")
            print(".----", end=" ")
         if (i == "2")
            print("..---", end=" ")
         if (i == "3")
            print("...--", end=" ")
         if (i == "4")
            print("....-", end=" ")
         if (i == "5")
            print(".....", end=" ")
         if (i == "6")
            print("-....", end=" ")
         if (i == "7")
            print("--...", end=" ")
         if (i == "8")
            print("---..", end=" ")
         if (i == "9")
            print("----.", end=" ")
         if (i == "0")
            print("-----", end=" ")
         if (i == " ")
            print("|", end=" ")
```

This code fails to compile and simply returns an invalid syntax error.

Comment: That's two different syntax errors in one line, one of which even the syntax highlighting here can tell you; it's not clear why you thought this *would* work. Also print is a *function* in 3.x.

Comment: `print("ewfew" if i == a")` is a syntax error. In particular, `"ewfew" if i == a"` is not a valid python expression. EDIT: and above that, `if (i == "a")` is missing a colon, `:`, so it is also a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, in my desperation to try to figure out what was wrong with my print statement, I made some sloppy changes and forgot to change it back to the "properly" syntaxed code. I originally did have colon's after each if statement, but the compiler told me to remove them. The final solution which works still does not have colons. Instead, it appears the key was changing the name of the variable from list to List?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot ":" for if statements and you forgot a string openning in this line `print("ewfew" if i == a")` these causes error and use elif after first if statement this way more efficent.

```
if statement1:
    ...
elif statement2:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

or you can create a dictionary for this job take a look at https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python/

Answer (score -1):

Wow, you have some errors in your code, so i solve them:

```
mode = input("Is you text in morse code? y/n")
if (mode == 'y'):
    print(" ")
else:
    List = list(i for i in input("Enter English text:"))
    #There is no :
    for i in List:
        if (i == "a"):
            #print("ewfew") #Threre was an extra "
            print(".-", end=" ") #Commentaries in Python creates by #
        if (i == "b"):
            print("-...", end=" ")
        if (i == "c"):
            print("-.-.", end=" ")
        if (i == "d"):
            print("-..", end=" ")
        if (i == "e"):
            print(".", end=" ")
        if (i == "f"):
            print("..-.", end=" ")
        if (i == "g"):
            print("--.", end=" ")
        if (i == "h"):
            print("....", end=" ")
        if (i == "i"):
            print("..", end=" ")
        if (i == "j"):
            print(".---", end=" ")
        if (i == "k"):
            print("-.-", end=" ")
        if (i == "l"):
            print(".-..", end=" ")
        if (i == "m"):
            print("--", end=" ")
        if (i == "n"):
            print("-.", end=" ")
        if (i == "o"):
            print("---", end=" ")
        if (i == "p"):
            print(".--.", end=" ")
        if (i == "q"):
            print("--.-", end=" ")
        if (i == "r"):
            print(".-.", end=" ")
        if (i == "s"):
            print("...", end=" ")
        if (i == "t"):
            print("-", end=" ")
        if (i == "u"):
            print("..-", end=" ")
        if (i == "v"):
            print("...-", end=" ")
        if (i == "w"):
            print(".--", end=" ")
        if (i == "x"):
            print("-..-", end=" ")
        if (i == "y"):
            print("-.--", end=" ")
        if (i == "z"):
            print("--..", end=" ")
        if (i == "1"):
            print(".----", end=" ")
        if (i == "2"):
            print("..---", end=" ")
        if (i == "3"):
            print("...--", end=" ")
        if (i == "4"):
            print("....-", end=" ")
        if (i == "5"):
            print(".....", end=" ")
        if (i == "6"):
            print("-....", end=" ")
        if (i == "7"):
            print("--...", end=" ")
        if (i == "8"):
            print("---..", end=" ")
        if (i == "9"):
            print("----.", end=" ")
        if (i == "0"):
            print("-----", end=" ")
        if (i == " "):
            print("|", end=" ")
```